# InfiniDB: Unable to perform DDL/DML error

Tags: infinidb

When I try to run 'Create Table' sql on infiniDB, I get the following error:

> "Error Code: 122 IDB-2010: Unable to perform DDL/DML because session
>   26 is currently updating another table."

The Create Table sql is nothing out of the ordinary, it's something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
 col_1 smallint,
 col_2 bigint,
 create_date datetime
) ENGINE = InfiniDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Why is this error occuring?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because InfiniDB is using a table locking model (at least for import jobs), so only a single modification can run on a table at a time.

In your case, there may be a job currently running or one that has crashed. This can cappen if i.e. cpimport segfaults. anyway, check the lock status with the command:

```
root@big1:~# /usr/local/Calpont/bin/viewtablelock 
 There is 1 table lock

  Table                       LockID  Process   PID    Session   Txn  CreationTime              State    DBRoots    
  mydb.stats_test             4673    cpimport  20855  BulkLoad  n/a  Wed Feb 18 11:48:04 2015  LOADING  1,2,3,4,5
```

if you are sure this process is not running anymore, you can kill and clean it up:

```
/usr/local/Calpont/bin/cleartablelock 4673
```